# Mitmproxy not working with snapchat or instagram

Tags: ios, instagram, mitmproxy, snapchat

So if I use mitmproxy on my mac and then connect to the proxy on my phone and install the certificate, I can inspect traffic from some apps like firefox, crossy road, etc. So it is definitely working. However, when I try to open Snapchat or instagram, the connection fails. I have done a bit of research and think it might be ssl pinning. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?